# How to do a sub regular-expression replacing in each matched groups of "main" regular-expression search?

Tags: c, regex, perl, hook

I'm working on something about hooking an existing lib. The implementation details are irrelevant to my question. In short, it is necessary for me to write a function definition for each original function in the lib like following:

```
void Hooked_OriginalFunctionName(int arg0, bool arg1, const char* arg2) {
   OriginalFunctionName(arg0,arg1,arg2);
   //Do other things:
}
```

Apparently it's a tedious work of manually writing headers(codes above "//Do other things" comment) of these functions, thus regular expression replace would be a better choice: I can just copy and paste original function declarations:

```
void OriginalFunction0(int arg0);
void OriginalFunction1(int arg0, bool arg1);
void OriginalFunction2(const char* arg0, int arg1);
... ...
```

And use regular expression to replace text which matches pattern:

```
void\s(\w+)\((.+)\);
```

with:

```
void Hooked_$1($2) {$1($2);//Do other things}
```

This approach can generate codes like:

```
void Hook_OriginalFunction2(const char* arg0, int arg1) {
    OriginalFunction2(const char* arg0, int arg1);
    //Do other things
}
```

However, formats of parameter list of the function calls are obviously wrong. So how can I subsequently replace

```
"const char* arg0, int arg1"
```

with

```
"arg0, arg1"
```

? Is it possible to do all these by only 1 regular expression replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perl script seems to do what you need. It uses the negative look-behind assertion to recognise what to remove from the list of attributes: non-whitespace not ending in a comma or right parenthesis, followed by a space.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my ($func, $args) = /void (\w+)\((.+)\);/) {
        print "void Hooked_$func($args) {\n";
        $args =~ s/\S+(?<![,)]) //g;
        print "    $func($args);\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
void OriginalFunction0(int arg0);
void OriginalFunction1(int arg0, bool arg1);
void OriginalFunction2(const char* arg0, int arg1);
void OriginalFunctionName(int arg0, bool arg1, const char* arg2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would prefer an approach using only one regular expression, though this script works. I'm not familiar with regex thus have no idea if it is possible.

Comment: Don't obsess about single regex solutions. Regular expressions are a programming language in their own right - so you can do most things. However they're also particularly badly designed for complex programming tasks, thanks to their legacy as a super search and replace, which means you end up with hard to read code.